# NGIX, Apache and Wordpress using proxy_pass

Tags: nginx, apache-2.4, wordpress, proxypass

**Background/Setup Information:**

Our main server uses NGIX as its base and we also have a cPanel server running our Wordpress installs etc.

On the main server I have used the following to point the url to the cPanel server

**NGIX.conf:**

```
location /private/ {
  include proxy-pass-settings.conf;
  proxy_pass  http://vps.domain.com/;
}
```

On the cPanel server I have created an account using `mainNGIXURL.com` with a subfolder within the `public_html` called `private` were the Wordpress install lives.

In the cPanel `public_html .htaccess` I have the following that does the redirect.

**.htaccess:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mainNGIXURL\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[0-9]+\..+\.cpaneldcv$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/[A-F0-9]{32}\.txt(?:\ Comodo\ DCV)?$
RewriteRule !^private/ /private%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```

Within the `private` Wordpress install I also have the WP `.htaccess` as follows

**.htaccess:**

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /private/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

My Wordpress site and home urls are set to `https://mainNGIXURL.com/private`

**Issue:**

When I try to access `https://mainNGIXURL.com/private/wp-admin` or `https://mainNGIXURL.com/private/wp-login.php` I seem to get redirected to `https://mainNGIXURL.com/404`

How can I make it so that I can run it correctly?

The front end seems to work 100% its just the admin area thats being strange

Comment: What on earth are you trying to do here?

Comment: @MichaelHampton Basically have https://mainNGIXURL.com/private run from a different server and have it 90% there just cant get the wp-admin

Comment: Did you check the logs? Did you check if correct requests arrive from Nginx? If Nginx sends a wrong request that doesn't exist in Apache / cPanel, it is bound to throw 404.

Comment: @PothiKalimuthu For the main /private I am getting HTTP 200 however for the wp-admin I am getting HTTP/1.1" 301 376 and 302